# Android WebViewClient with JavaScript Alerts/Prompt

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I am having the following problem:
My website i prompting me with this JavaScript Popup

[JS Popup Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c2QP.png)

I need to create this wrapper for the webSite and I need somehow to process this dialog.
 I have tried using ChromeWebView Client but my website is not loading at all with it.
I tried adding both WebView and ChromeWebView Clients to my WebView but it is still not working. 
Here is some of my code:

```html
        String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("currentUrl");
    this.myWebView.loadUrl(text);

    WebViewClient webViewClientProceedSSL = new ProceedSSLClient(myWebView);
    this.myWebView.setWebViewClient(webViewClientProceedSSL);
    this.myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Do you have any ideas how can i fix that?

Edit 1:
I have forgotten to add my WebView Settings. Here are they:

```
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Edit 2:

I have tried overriding both methods onJsAlert and onJsPrompt in the WebChromeClient class when setting it to the webView. This is not working as well...

```
  myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }
    });
```

I am not getting in that method at All - I tried logging something in it and debugging it. I never got in.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way of showing the form in my web-view.If there is not way, can you tell me when I should create that request and how can I do that?

Comment: Sorry for my wrong reading the question. Did you try `webview.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` ??

Comment: webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Comment: @Toaster There are my Settings

Comment: I think you need to override `onJsAlert()` and do modification there by extending the web-chrome client

Comment: I tried logging something there and debugging it and i never get in that method..

Comment: What do you mean by never got that method?

Comment: I am never getting in that method is what I am saying..

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the Webview

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Also try adding this method in WebViewClient

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   @Override
   public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
   //Required functionality here
      return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have added the settings to my question. This is not working for me..

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check it and try once. @IvelinIliev

Comment: I have tried that. Overriding both onJsAlert and/or onJsPrompt. No success here again..

Comment: Have you tried for any other website? If it isn't personal, I would like to check the site. Try opening the site in mobile browser. @IvelinIliev

Comment: Sorry, I am accessing the website with VPN connection you won't be open it. When i open it in my mobile chrome browser i am gettting that Pop-up. When opened with my android webView i am getting nothing.

Comment: Ok. Did you try `setWebviewClient` method?

Comment: Yeah, but `setWebviewClient` does not accept WebChromeClient objects.

Comment: Use both WebviewClient object for `setWebviewClient` and WebChromeClient object for `setWebChromeClient` and try it.